# print values at fixed position in Terminal window using UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I am running a shell script which produces below output.

```
Built-By : apache

Created-By : Apache Maven

Implementation-Title : testApp

Implementation-Vendor-Id : com.test.app

Implementation-Version : testBox

Manifest-Version : 1.0

appname : TestStar

build-date : 02-03-2014-13 : 41

version : testBox
```

**Expecting the below output: (Please ignore _ underscore)**

```
Built-By_________________: apache

Created-By_______________: Apache Maven

Implementation-Title_____: testApp

Implementation-Vendor-Id_: com.test.app

Implementation-Version___: testBox

Manifest-Version_________: 1.0

appname__________________: TestStar

build-date_______________: 02-03-2014-13 : 41

version__________________: testBox
```

Someone Please help me. I am iterating two arrays to print these values.

Comment: It would help if you could describe what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show me your code.

maybe this would help:

`#!/bin/bash
key=("appname" "version" "Created-By")
value=("TestStar" "testBox" "Apache Maven")
for i in "${!key[@]}";do
    printf "%-15s %s\n" "${key[i]}" "${value[i]}"
done`